# Reserved word in XML tag

Tags: xml, flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, e4x

```
<node>left</node>
<class></class>
<et>16,471</et>
```

When I get tag `class`, I see error `1084`, because `class` is reserved word

```
vars["class1"] = result.item[0].class;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
vars["class1"] = result.item[0]["class"];
```

This should work